# Should you open files in 'wb' mode when encoding is unknown?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, png

The problem that I'm having with my test image is what I like to call the "It looks like we don't support this file format." error since thats what it says when I open the image.

```
try:
    with open('GA-image test.png',encoding='utf8') as File:
        FileBytes = File.read(1000000000)
        TypeOfEncoding = 'utf8'
except:
    try:
        with open('GA-image test.png',encoding='Latin-1') as File:
            FileBytes = File.read(1000000000)
            TypeOfEncoding = 'Latin-1'
#To shorten this code I'm just going to give two of the types of encoding

with open('GA-image test2.png','wb') as FileW:
    print(TypeOfEncoding)
    FileBytes2 = str.encode(FileBytes)
    FileBytes3 = FileW.write(FileBytes2)
```

This is a link to this code and the test image that I used:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/496421060565139466/548261637782503425/Reading_and_writing_a_file_useing_file_bytes.zip

Answer (score 1):

Image data is *not text*, don't open images in text mode. Not for reading, and not for writing.

In Python, you open files in one of two modes: text mode, and binary mode, using `t` or `b` in the `mode` argument. If you use neither, `t` is implied.

Text mode is merely an extra layer on top of binary mode where the binary data is translated from and to *text*, using a [standard text codec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html). The vast majority of image formats, including PNG, are not text formats, and you can't decode their data with a text codec.

So always open these in binary mode, adding in the `b` character in the file mode:

```
with open('GA-image test.png', 'rb') as image_file:
    image_bytes = image_file.read()

with open('GA-image test2.png', 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(image_bytes)
```

Text codecs are just one form of storing information in a series of bytes, image formats such as PNG are another, and are not designed to have meaning as text. That you can always decode image data as Latin-1 is a *coincidence*, an accident of how the Latin-1 codec is designed, and not intentional.

As a side note: it is usually a bad idea to use `except`, as it catches *all* exceptions, not just errors with opening a file or decoding errors that will always spring from trying to read PNG data as UTF-8. Use specific exceptions, wherever possible.